# Redis memory ocupation Store and AddToRecentsList

Tags: c#, redis

I'm new in Redis and would really appreciate if you can help with this.

I have a simple class

```
    public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Profession { get; set; }
}
```

with following

```
     public void StorePerson( Person Item)
 {
 using (var redisClient = redisManager.GetClient())
            {
                var redisPerson = redisClient.As<Person>();
                redisPerson.Store(item);
                IRedisList<Person> ListOfPeople = redis.Lists["urn:people"];
                ListOfPeople.AddToRecentsList(item);


            }
    }
```

Will this code store the same Person on two places or one (the list is just a pointer to Person)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what library do you use for accessing Redis. Redis is an string key-value store, so no references will be kept there (API used can implement it somehow). For KEYS and LISTs are used different commands, very good description is in this [Data type tutorial](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro).

Comment: I'm using service stack. Thanks for the link will check it